# Long boot times, ACPI error messages in dmesg

Tags: bios, acpi

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed Ubuntu 19.10 to my new laptop from a flash drive using Rufus. I have nvidia 1660 ti working now on Ubuntu but I am experiencing extremely long boot times.

This is what `dmesg` returns:

````
[    0.212539] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.212546] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.212548] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.212597] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.212601] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.212603] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.212604] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.212607] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.212608] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.215043] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.215047] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.215049] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.215050] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.215053] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.215054] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.217473] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.217476] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.217478] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.217480] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.217482] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.217483] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.219901] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.219905] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.219906] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.219908] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.219910] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.219912] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.222324] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.222327] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.222329] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.224748] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.224752] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.224753] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.224755] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.224757] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.224759] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.227173] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.227176] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.227178] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.229595] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.229599] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.229600] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.232020] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.232023] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.232025] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.232026] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.232029] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.232030] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.234443] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.234446] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.234448] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.236867] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.236871] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.236872] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.239285] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.239289] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.239290] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.241707] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.241710] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.241712] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.244130] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.244133] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.244135] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.244136] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.244139] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.244140] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246529] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-159)
[    0.246532] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246534] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.246536] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-159)
[    0.246539] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246541] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.246568] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246571] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246572] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246574] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246576] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246578] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246610] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246613] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246614] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246616] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246618] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246620] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246652] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246655] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246656] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246658] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246660] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246662] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246693] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246696] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246698] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246699] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246701] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246703] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246735] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246738] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246739] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246769] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246772] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246773] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246801] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246804] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246805] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246833] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246836] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246837] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246865] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246868] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246869] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.246897] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[    0.246900] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.246901] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.248196] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-159)
[    0.248200] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[    0.248202] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.248229] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/dswload2-159)
[    0.248232] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)```
````

Comment: You  need to file a bugreport against `acpi`. The error is likely due to unsupported hardware or a bug in your BIOS  You are missing a ton of information a bug report needs. As an example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1804577 see the list of commands asked there.

Comment: I just did , how fast do you think they will response ??

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSaber did you ever get a response?